# ¿Cuál es el nombre de esta verdura que parece el cruce entre una coliflor, un brócoli y un fractal?

Tags: solicitud-de-término, vocabulario-técnico, comida

El otro día apareció un nuevo usuario que tenía en la foto de perfil esta verdura, que parece el cruce entre una coliflor, un brócoli y un fractal.

[image]

¿Cuál es el nombre de esta verdura?

Comment: Yo lo conozco como *romanescu*, acabado en *u* y con ese nombre aparece también en muchos sitios, en otros *romanesco*. ¿Dependerá de zonas llamarlo de una forma u otra?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

De [Wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romanesco_(br%C3%A9col)):

> El **romanesco** o **romicia** (*Brassica oleracea*) es un híbrido de brécol (*Brassica oleracea var. italica*) y coliflor (*Brassica oleracea var. botrytis*) de la familia de las brasicáceas. El **brécol romanesco** fue documentado inicialmente en Italia (como *Broccolo romanesco*) en el siglo XVI.

[image]